# Iptables от простого к сложному

Tags: iptables, debian

Есть пк с двумя сетевыми,

```
eth0 192.168.0.100 (есть инет)eth1 10.150.7.100 (корп сеть)
```

как обьяснить Debian"у чтобы он видел обе подсети корректно?

Answer (score 1):

Debian-сервак собсно который с двумя картами? Ну сперва настроить оба интерфейса, потом сделать форвадинг (если кому-то в корпоративной сети нужен инет) + прикрутить нат (опять если надо же).

Почитайте мою тему [вирутальные и не очень машины и сети](http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/3173/вирутальные-и-не-очень-машины-и-сети). Там я как раз настраивал форвардинг и переброс соединения.

Если же все действительно на уровне - видеть обе сети - то тогда настроить маршрутизацию в корпоративной сети еще, чтоб он видел все компы в ней, а они могли достучаться до сервера.

Answer (score 1):

А он их нормально будет видеть. Если же он должен работать шлюзом, то

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

временное решение, а так оно должно быть в `/etc/-где-то-там` типа `sysconfig.conf` или что-то такое.

```
iptables -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.1XX - адрес сервакаiptables -I POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j SNAT --to-source 10.150.7.1XX - адрес сервака
```

А если у всех клиентов указан шлюз, то даже SNAT не нужен, всё само будет работать.

Comment: Угу.Спасибо за коммент.Действительно автоматически ставится форадинг в файле /etc/sysctl.confПросто открываем в редакторе от рута/судо и раскоментировать нужные строки.А по автоматизации,дабы не вписывать каждый раз проброс соединений в айпитейблес и не востанавилвать их командой iptables-restore можно сделать так как описано http://kubuntu.ru/nat-iptables